# How to make a flat ring in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I was able to make a donut with Three.js using THREE.TorusGeometry.  But I can't get it to look like a flat ring like the ones in these pictures:

http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.titanjewellery.co.uk/Mens/TI21-Titanium-8mm-Flat-Brushed-Ring.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.titanjewellery.co.uk/Mens/8mm-Brushed-Titanium-Flat-Ring.html&h=301&w=232&sz=16&tbnid=LCN7eQuo2wyG_M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=69&zoom=1&usg=__3vayMvDy26tsj2hwvCK9SsYwVwY=&docid=ZMdcBBBQOzMSoM&sa=X&ei=pEhsUeL4FKWJiAKCzIHYCQ&ved=0CEAQ9QEwBA&dur=1660

Here's what my donut looks like:
[image]

Is there another Three.js geometry that can generate a flat ring (right with flat inner and outer walls)?  Or another way of going about this?

Thanks for any pointers you can share! :)

Update:
The code and dependencies were taken from:

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>three.js webgl - trackball controls</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        color: #000;
        font-family:Monospace;
        font-size:13px;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight: bold;

        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #info {
        color:#000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px; width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      a {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info">
      <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - trackball controls example</br>MOVE mouse &amp; press LEFT/A: rotate, MIDDLE/S: zoom, RIGHT/D: pan
    </div>

    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="stats.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
      var container, stats;
      var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
      var cross;

      init();
      animate();

      function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 500;

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
        controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
        controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
        controls.noZoom = false;
        controls.noPan = false;
        controls.staticMoving = true;
        controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
        controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

        // world
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

        var radius = 100;
        var tubeRadius = 50;
        var radialSegments = 8 * 10;
        var tubularSegments = 6 * 15;
        var arc = Math.PI * 2;
        var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( radius, tubeRadius, radialSegments, tubularSegments, arc );
        var material =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

        for ( var i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {
          var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
          mesh.updateMatrix();
          mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
          scene.add( mesh );
        } 

        // lights
        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
        light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
        scene.add( light );

        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
        renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        //

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
      }

      function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        controls.handleResize();
        render();
      }

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();
      }

      function render() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alininja/b4qGx/1/

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I've updated the question with the code and JSFiddle.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. Use [TubeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TubeGeometry) - this is probably what you need
2. [ExtrudeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) to extrude a disk
3. lathe an offset rectangle with [LatheGeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397545/extruding-with-three-js/11423521#11423521)
4. Use THREE.Shape -> grab the tube like shape from the [webgl_geometry_shapes sample](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html)

Comment: Thanks George.  I was trying to use TubeGeometry earlier, but couldn't figure out how to define a path for one of it's inputs:https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/TubeGeometry.js.  Do you know of any tutorials on the path object?  Thanks again!

Comment: @AL You can see how the Path and TubeGeometry are used in the [webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes.html). For a basic tube you need a to extrude a circle along a line for example :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again.  But I made some progress, but got stuck with trying to get the spline to curve the right way.  If you have some time to spare can you please point me in the right direction (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180743/how-to-get-three-extrudegeometry-to-curve-with-three-splinecurve3)?  Thanks again for helping me get this far.  Take care!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RingGeometry function. The following code adds to the scene a full (between 0 and 360 degrees) wireframed red ring of inner radius equals to 10 and outer radio equals to 20. You can play with the other indicated variables to adjust the aspect of the disc you want to generate ()

```
var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(10, 20, thetaSegments, phiSegments, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var ring = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true}));
ring.position.set(25, 30, 0);
scene.add(ring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code!

```
var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 3, 0.5, 20, 2999 );
  ring1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true}));
scene.add(ring1);
```