# SVG spline (with Bézier curve) to three.js lathe object

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, spline

- I am creating a model of the [theme building](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LAX_LA.jpg#/media/File:LAX_LA.jpg) at LAX airport for a game I writing

I am looking at a way to take svg spline (with Bézier curve) and convert it the lathe object in three.js?

- model it in 3D modeller, that wont work as I am using continuous LODing and want to send the smallest amount of data from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'fastest' approach in terms of data-transmission from the server to the client would be:

1. Send your spline/curve to the client from server
2. Convert curve to
   polygon in client
3. Create Lathe in client from the polygon

---

You would first need to **convert your SVG spline into a polygon**, which you will then feed into Three.js as a `Lathe` Geometry.

As for the amount of data - it depends on how high is the fidelity of your curve-to-polygon conversion(how many samples/subdivisions you want to use when converting the curve to a polygon) but since this could be done in the client(*see code snippet below*) then you wouldn't worry too much about it.

---

- For creating a `Lathe` Geometry out of a series of points see [this
  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397545/extruding-with-three-js)
- For converting an `SVG curve` to a series of points you can use this
  piece of code:

  ```
  //convert path to polygon
  function pathToPolygon(path, samples) {

  if (!samples) samples = 0;

  var poly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');

  // Put all path segments in a queue
  for (var segs = [], s = path.pathSegList, i = s.numberOfItems - 1; i >= 0; --i) segs[i] = s.getItem(i);
  var segments = segs.concat();

  var seg, lastSeg, points = [],
      x, y;
  var addSegmentPoint = function(s) {
      if (s.pathSegType == SVGPathSeg.PATHSEG_CLOSEPATH) {

      } else {
          if (s.pathSegType % 2 == 1 && s.pathSegType > 1) {
              // All odd-numbered path types are relative, except PATHSEG_CLOSEPATH (1)
              x += s.x;
              y += s.y;
          } else {
              x = s.x;
              y = s.y;
          }
          var lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];
          if (!lastPoint || x != lastPoint[0] || y != lastPoint[1]) points.push([x, y]);
      }
  };
  for (var d = 0, len = path.getTotalLength(), step = len / samples; d <= len; d += step) {
      var seg = segments[path.getPathSegAtLength(d)];
      var pt = path.getPointAtLength(d);
      if (seg != lastSeg) {
          lastSeg = seg;
          while (segs.length && segs[0] != seg) addSegmentPoint(segs.shift());
      }
      var lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];
      if (!lastPoint || pt.x != lastPoint[0] || pt.y != lastPoint[1]) points.push([pt.x, pt.y]);
  }
  for (var i = 0, len = segs.length; i < len; ++i) addSegmentPoint(segs[i]);
  for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; ++i) points[i] = points[i].join(',');
  poly.setAttribute('points', points.join(' '));
  return points;
  }
  ```

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using Bézier curve also

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was talking about - the function above converts SVG path elements that have bezier curves as their 'd' attribute. It will return to you a series of points. So take your SVG paths(if you only have the bezier points just construct an SVG path with your bezier points as 'd' attribute) and pass it into the func above - it will return to you an array of points that can be passed into Three.js's constructors as geometry