# How to create perfect ring geometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, web, three.js

I need to create perfect ring geometry in three.js. I am looking for something like this:

[image: ring image]

I spend more than a day to find how to do this, and I am stuck with code like this:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
ring = '';
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('img/water.jpg', function ( texture ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 5, 1, 8, 1900 );
    ring = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, wireframe: true}));
    scene.add(ring);
});

camera.position.z = 20;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    ring.rotation.y = 0.4;

    renderer.render(scene,camera);
};

render();
```

**EDIT:**

My code has changed, and now it looks like this:

```
            var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var group;

        var targetRotation = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 100, 350, 00 );
            scene.add( camera );

            var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.9 );
            camera.add( light );

            group = new THREE.Group();
            group.position.y = 0;
            scene.add( group );

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var texture = loader.load( "img/metal.png" );
            texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.set( 0.008, 0.008 );

            function addShape( shape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s ) {

                // flat shape with texture
                // note: default UVs generated by ShapeGemoetry are simply the x- and y-coordinates of the vertices

                var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: color } ) );
                mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
                mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );
                mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
                group.add( mesh );

            }

            // Arc circle 1
            var x = 0, y = 0;
            var arcShape1 = new THREE.Shape();
            arcShape1.moveTo( 0, 0 );
            arcShape1.absarc( 10, 10, 11, 0, Math.PI*2, false );

            var holePath1 = new THREE.Path();
            holePath1.moveTo( 20, 10 );
            holePath1.absarc( 10, 10, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true );
            arcShape1.holes.push( holePath1 );
            //

            // Arc circle 2
            var x = 0, y = 0;
            var arcShape2 = new THREE.Shape();
            arcShape2.moveTo( 0, 0 );
            arcShape2.absarc( 10, 10, 13, 0, Math.PI*2, false );

            var holePath2 = new THREE.Path();
            holePath2.moveTo( 25, 10 );
            holePath2.absarc( 10, 10, 12, 0, Math.PI*2, true );
            arcShape2.holes.push( holePath2 );
            //

            var extrudeSettings = { amount: 1.6, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 30, steps: 30, bevelSize: 0.3, bevelThickness: 1.5, curveSegments: 100 };

            // addShape( shape, color, x, y, z, rx, ry,rz, s );

            //addShape( heartShape,       extrudeSettings, 0xf00000,   60,  100, 0, 0, 0, Math.PI, 1 );
            addShape( arcShape1, extrudeSettings, 0xffc107,  -35, -30, -20, 0, 0, 0, 4 );
            addShape( arcShape2, extrudeSettings, 0xffc107,  -40, -22, -50, 0, 0.6, 0, 4 );

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
            group.castShadow = true;
            group.receiveShadow = false;

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();

        }

        function render() {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

The result looks like this:

[image: better rings]

And now the questions: how to make this line on the ring dissapear, how to make my ring more shiny, how to make my ring more 'circular' on the left and right side?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397545/extruding-with-three-js

Comment: I already tried this.. :/

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: How many polygons / vertices "perfect ring geometry" should contain?

Answer (score 1):

Should works fine. It was the bevel at junction at PI*2 causing the 'line' thing. You can solve the problem by overlapping the two edges of the curve.

```
        arcShape1.absarc( 10, 10, 11, 0, Math.PI*1.99, false );
        holePath1.absarc( 10, 10, 10, 0, Math.PI*2.01, true );

        arcShape2.absarc( 10, 10, 13, 0, Math.PI*1.99, false );
        holePath2.absarc( 10, 10, 12, 0, Math.PI*2.01, true );
```

[! Please click to see the screenshot. I do not have enough reputation to post the picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYzmZ.png)

Comment: ''*Should works fine.*" How and why? State in your answer itself buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by adding more light sources in various locations and color, I could increase perceived reflectivity and shine, but this is assuming it is the only object in the scene.